# How to differentiate between an adjective and past participal?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

See these examples of 'settled' as an adjective and participle

1. Children are settled now in new school.(adjective)
2. Children are settled by the teacher in the bus.(participle)
3. Now all my friends are settled for less.(adjective)
4. Now all my friends are settled by themselves.(participle)

This for example I know about 'participle adjectives' but still I am not able to distinguish between them.